# about the malloc in c pointers

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am stuck with basics of pointers Here are my code

```
char *orderUp;

orderdup = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));

printf("enter string");
scanf("\n%s",orderdup);
printf("\n%s",orderdup);// gives scanned strings
printf("\n%s",*orderdup);// gives empty string
```

Here This program is running fine . I want to know that why in  printf statement giving the scanned string.I mean it should print the address but why it is printing string and last printf statement gives empty string.

Comment: Because `%s` is making `printf` to expect a pointer. "Empty" string is one of the outcomes of the undefined behavior you are invoking by passing it `char` instead.

Comment: `*orderup` is a single `char` and is the first position of the memory you allocated with malloc.  You should have gotten a compiler warning for the line `printf("\n%s",*orderdup);` since the `%s` format specifier expects a char pointer (i.e. string), and you supplied a single char.

Comment: What about the man-page of `printf` is unclear? Did you even read it? What does your C book say? If you are learning C from youtube videos or online tutorials: ask their authors! They apparently taught rubbish.

Comment: Curious, what or who suggested "it should print the address" ?

Comment: I was just curious as I am thinking orderup contains address of char so it should print address.but now I am clear that it depends on format specifier(%s or %p).the pointer appears very confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

`*orderdup` is of `char` type. You are using `%s` specifier to print a `char` data type while `%s` expects a `char *` data type. It will invoke undefined behavior. To print address use `%p`

```
printf("%p", (void*)orderdup);
```

Comment: And to print the first character (if that's what's intended), use `%c`.